# Did the Israeli paper Ma'ariv run an article titled "The Jews Who Run Clinton's Court" in 1994?

Tags: united-states, politics, judaism, antisemitism

In January 2018, [Puerto Rico's central newspaper El Nuevo Dia ran an op-ed accusing Congress of being "controlled by Jews,"](http://www.latinorebels.com/2018/01/21/dear-wilda-rodriguez-we-jews-do-not-control-the-united-states-or-the-world-opinion/) on the following evidence:

> “More than 20 years ago, the Israeli newspaper Ma’ariv (second largest
>   newspaper in Israel) had an article in Hebrew that explained how the
>   Jews control Washington,” she wrote. “For Israelis, recognizing Jewish
>   power over Washington is not an offensive statement. It is the victory
>   of the diaspora.”

I believe the source for the Ma'ariv article is [this online translation, attributed to peace activist Israel Shahak](https://www.islam-radio.net/islam/english/toread/collect.htm). However, that website also attributes a quote to Ariel Sharon about Jews controlling Congress, [the authenticity of which is disputed](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36930/did-ariel-sharon-say-that-the-jewish-people-control-america).

Is the article in question real?

Comment: While I can't address the main claim Ma'ariv is nothing like the second largest paper in Israel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_newspapers_in_Israel

Comment: The supplement section of Maariw 2 Sep 94 is on archive.org https://archive.org/details/Maariv1994IsraelHebrew/page/n5 but all links that might contain readable resolutions lead to nowhere for me…

Comment: @LorenPechtel  I don't know anything about newspapers in Israel, but the article about Maariv (also on wikipedia) says "It is second in sales after Yedioth Ahronoth and third in readership [...]"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maariv_(newspaper)
I don't fully understand the contradicting figures, but maybe it can be partially explained because "Israel Post" and "Israel Hayom" are distributed for free, and either counted or not...  still the figures don't seem to match in the two wikipedia articles.

Comment: Israel Hayom began in 2007. I would guess Maariv was indeed second in both sales and readership, behind Yediot Ahronot, in 1994.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article seems real, but mentions **influence**, not **control**.

There seems to be a bit of a mix up about who said what:

1. An article published in the Israeli newspaper Maariv in 1994, authored by Israeli reporter Avinoam Bar-Yosef.
2. Highlights and commentary by Anti-Zionist Jewish activist Israel Shahak, published on the antisemitic web site www.islam-radio.net.

I failed to find the original article, and have to rely on [the translation posted in islam-radio](https://www.islam-radio.net/islam/english/toread/collect.htm). Though it's published in a biased site, the translation itself seems legitimate to me, and contains no claims an Israeli journalist would be unlikely to make. The highlights and comments, however, are by Israel Shahak, and were not published in an Israeli newspaer. Same for the antisemitic caricature below.

Israel Shahak chooses to highlight some parts of the article, that talk about Jewish influence, and chooses not to highlights parts that don't sit well with his narrative (e.g. highlighting *"the president's office which is full of warm Jews"* and not *"first and foremost since they are Americans and their primary loyalty is towards America"*).

So bottom line, the author does talk about the many Jews which are in prominent positions in the American administration, and says that there are now (i.e. 1994) more of them than ever. He did not write that they "run Clinton's court" (as in the question's title). He talks about Jewish power **in** Washington, not **over** it.

Comment: There are quite different 'translations' floating around. They seem based on the article that is linked to in the second comment below the Q. From what I can make out *there* it is not even influence but more integration?

Comment: @LangLangC, he does say that many Jews have influence in Washington, and also that it's a sign of integration into American society.